# enter key to move between form fields not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

i use enter key to move between form fields but its not working:

cursor is not moving to another field in the form if i tap enter key.

if i remove submit button it works.

it is not moving because of submit button.

what should i do know help me friends.

```
<HTML>
<Head>
<Script Language=JavaScript>

function toEOT(isField){

isRange = isField.createTextRange();
isRange.move('textedit');
isRange.select();
}

function actTab(isField){

if (event.keyCode == 13)
{
nextField = isField.tabIndex;
nextField++;
if (nextField < document.forms.Form1.length)
{document.forms.Form1[nextField].focus()}
else {document.forms.Form1[0].focus()}
}
}

function init(){

document.forms.Form1[0].focus();
}

window.onload=init;

</Script>
</Head>
<Body>
<Form name='Form1'>
<fieldset>
<legend>Fills</legend>
<input type=text value="This is Some Text" size=25 onFocus="toEOT(this)" onKeyUp="actTab(this)" tabindex='1'><br>
<input type=text value="Some Text" size=25 onFocus="toEOT(this)" onKeyUp="actTab(this)" tabindex='2'><br>
<input type=text value="Nothing" size=25 onFocus="toEOT(this)" onKeyUp="actTab(this)" tabindex='3'><br>
<input type=text value="Two Words" size=25 onFocus="toEOT(this)" onKeyUp="actTab(this)" tabindex='4'><br>
<select >
<option>geetha</option>
<option>geetha</option>
<option>geetha</option>
</select>
<select >
<option>geetha</option>
<option>geetha</option>
<option>geetha</option>
</select>
<input type=text value="Two Words" size=25 /><br>
<input style="margin:20px 20px 20px 250px;" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</fieldset>
</Form>

</Body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I feel I should note that this seems a little... strange. The tab key is used by default to cycle through form fields. Why change it to a key that is recognised as the key to submit the form? Something to think about exactly why you should need to do this

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier just to make the enter key behave like the tab key as there wont be any other major use for it.

```
    function checkKey(e){
    if( e.keyCode == 13 ){ // if enter key
        var e = jQuery.Event('keydown'); // create a manual event
        e.which = e.charCode = 0;
        e.keyCode = 9; // set the new event to "tab"
        $(this.target).trigger(e); // trigger the new event (on the document)
        return false;  // cancels the original "enter" event from executing
        }
    }

    $(document).on('keydown', checkKey);
```